# Google sheets query - I would like to return a column, but if cells in the column are empty return cells in another column instead

Tags: sql, google-sheets

Kinda new at this, struggling with a solution.

So currently my formula looks like this:

```
=Transpose(Query(importrange("1XlxiJwGNEEgeV7qAbN4QXR1vustupeUMs5tOLI8qm54","2020 LNA!A:K"), "select Col8 where Col2 contains '"&P136&"' AND Col8 is not null offset 1"))
```

Col2 is my criteria and remains constant. What I'm looking to do is have the formula return the cell in Col9 if the cell in Col8 is empty. If the cell in Col8 is not empty it will just return as is.

Col8 is not null is to prevent returning empty spillover rows after the data.

Ideally I would use the case function but that isn't present for Sheets. Would love to hear any input, do let me know if more info/clarity is needed as well.

EDIT: Added pictures for reference. Image 1 is a separate workbook, Image 2 is desired output (E2:J2) with D1 as criteria

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAvIn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR2bM.png)

Comment: share a copy (sample) of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Added! Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(
 "URL_or_ID_here", "2020 LNA!A2:C"), 
 "select Col2,Col3 where Col1 = '"&A1&"'", 0)), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for this! I'm getting an error "Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2". If I remove the parent query it works but without excluding the null rows. Is this because I'm referencing a range from another workbook?

Comment: Yes I've allowed access! I've created two test workbooks with the exact configuration. The formula is highlighted in Yellow in the second document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wYa5EWlmMZXv4qMr6Iprs8xv87ckREewLRS8aTtnspg/edit?usp=sharing       |        https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JAMHKlztp5rpd-pRdHb2AW3oI1p03UGKGhLPVSQieYw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: both sheets are private

Comment: Sorry, both should be accessible now!

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U65HGRPIkY0Tjt_2xo3pGFlPQbAIk85egKuKBAdrbAc/edit#gid=0

Comment: ahhhhh I see! Thanks so much you're a lifesaver. I have to go learn more about Flatten now. Really appreciate it, have a great weekend!